# Route :_id communicate with schema _id field in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a path that looks like this `path: '/speakers/singleDetails/:_id'` and a schema with a field like this

```
speakerId: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function(){
        return this.params._id;
    }
 }
```

I want the `autoValue` of the `speakerId` field to return the `/:_id` that is appended to the `path`, but I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`

**UPDATE**

I now set my `idPath` in my router and `get` it in collection schema

```
 onBeforeAction: function(){
    console.log(this.params._id);
    Session.set('idPath', this.params._id);
    this.next();
}
```

---

```
speakerId: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function(){
        return Session.get('idPath');
    }
}
```

But now I get this error: `Exception in delivering result of invoking '/singleDetails/insert': Error: Internal server error [500]`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't have a Session with the `_id?`

Like this. on the Route

```
Session.set('idPath',this.params._id);
```

and on the schema.

```
speakerId: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function(){
       if (this.isInsert) {
        return Session.get('idPath');
      } 
    }
 }
```

Check into [Aldeed/Meteor-collections2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#autovalue) for more information about autoValue Method.

Comment: `Error: Internal server error [500]` can i see the logs on your console? the server console

Comment: the `speakerId` field does not `autoValue`; it forces me to enter a value for it.

Comment: try sorting the value inside a variable and later insert it? if you open the console an type `Session.get('idPath')` what do you get?