# Passing id between router and collection, Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to use `Session.set()` in my router and `Session.get()` with `autoValue` in my schema, but `Session.get()` is undefined within my schema scope.  How can I pass the value of the current `id` (as it is appended to the end of my URL) to `autoValue` in my schema?

```
    //collections/singleDetails.js

    singleDetails = new Meteor.Collection('singleDetails');

    singleDetails.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({

        location: {
            type: String,
            label: 'location',
            max: 200,
            optional: true
        },

        number: {
            type: Number,
            label: 'number of attendees',
            max: 2000,
            optional: true
        },

        occasion: {
            type: String,
            label: 'occasion for speech'
        },

        speakerId: {
            type: String,
            autoValue: function(){
                Session.get('pathId');
            }
        }

    }));
```

And here is the router

```
    //client/views/singleDetails.js

    Router.route('singleDetails', {
        path: '/speakers/singleDetails/:_id',
        template: 'singleDetails',
        data: function(){
            return Speakers.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
        },
        onBeforeAction: function(){
            console.log(this.params._id);
            Session.set('pathId', this.params._id);
            this.next();
        }
    });

    Template.singleDetails.helpers({

        singleDetails: function(){
            return singleDetails.find({});
        }
    });
```

Comment: [this is not the same question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350623/route-id-communicate-with-schema-id-field-in-meteor/28350699#28350699)

Comment: Try this and tell me what you get.
 `speakerId: {
            type: String,
            autoValue: function(){
                var ses = Session.get('pathId');
               console.log(ses)
            }
        }`

Comment: it logs the proper `id`

Comment: did you still have the chat room open?

Comment: no i dont still have it open

Comment: how do we re-instate the chat?